# Identical style boxes except colour. One works the other doesn't. Stumped

Tags: html, css

I have two styles set up to place a coloured box under text. Each is identical except for the colour chosen.
In the body I have two sentences. For one I put the paragraph ID as greenbox and the second paragraph as orangebox. The green box works perfectly but the orange box is invisible when testing.
If I change the second paragraph's ID to greenbox it works, so it seems that there is an issue with the orangebox style but it is identical to the greenbox except for the colour code used.

I have even checked my css file to make sure I don't have the greenbox style in there which could make it work and the other not.
Am I missing a glaring error?

Style codes placed within the  tags:

```
        greenbox {
        background-color: #073004;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }

    orangebox {
        background-color: #FFAB38;
        padding: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

The text with the styled paragraphs:

```
<body>

<section id="maincontent">

        <p id="greenbox"; style="font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: bold; font-weight: 600; font-size: large; color:white; text-align:center;">Text to be in a green box with white lettering!
        </p>
        
        <br>

        <div id="bannerimage" align="center">
            <img src="images/land index banner small trans logo.png" style="width:100%; height:auto; margin:0 auto; alt=""/></div>

            <br><br>
            
        <p id="orangebox"; style="font-family: Arial, Gotham, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-style: bold; font-weight: 600; font-size: large; color:black; text-align:center;">Text to be in a orange box with black lettering!
        </p>
```

I am at a loss as to why the 'orangebox' style does not work, but 'greenbox' does for either paragraph.

Comment: You are missing `#` from your selectors

Comment: It is unclear how greenbox would work with what you provided.

Comment: Have you copied your code accurately? The typo in your selectors indicate that neither of those “boxes” would, or even  could, work.

Comment: Thank you. I will correct it. That was what was puzzling me: why one would work but the other wouldn't. I assumed maybe I had originally placed a correct code for greenbox within my css stylesheet but I hadn't.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the id selector you have to use # before the name. It is missing in the code you put here. Otherwise this works fine.
You can refer https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp, You have to use selectors properly

Comment: Thank you. I decided to use the style as a class instead so used a '.' instead and it has worked great. Did not know about the # in front of the name for an ID. I had looked at guides and with the greenbox working I thought I had done it correctly. Always learning. All you guys are great.